# Responsive Table glitch with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some issues making my table responsive.

In fact the headings aren't aligning with the content below. Can someone help me out?

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    
    <div class="table-responsive">

<table>

 <thead>
  <th>Subject</th>
  <th>Dates</th>
  <th>Time</th>
  <th>With</th>
  <th>Cost</th>
 </thead>

<tr style="display:block"><td class="elist-title"><a href="/events/winter/">Winter</a></td><td class="elist-date">27 February 2016 </td><td class="elist-time">10:00am - 4:00pm</td><td class="elist-with">Gordon Peterson&nbsp;</td><td class="elist-cost"></td></tr>

</table>

</div>
    
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/ppq3xxwv/

Thank you.

Comment: I hope this is not a joke.. remove `style="display:block"` from the `<tr>`

Comment: @AlexG Oh dear, oh dear. How did I miss that?!

Comment: Sorry though if I sounded rude x)

Comment: @AlexG Not at all. I should keep a closer eye on my code. Thank you for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `inline style` in `tr` & Add class table like `table`

```
<tr /*style="display:block"*/><td class="elist-title"><a href="/events/winter/">Winter</a></td><td class="elist-date">27 February 2016 </td><td class="elist-time">10:00am - 4:00pm</td><td class="elist-with">Gordon Peterson&nbsp;</td><td class="elist-cost"></td></tr>

<table class="table">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ppq3xxwv/1/

Comment: Thank you, Lalji!! :-) How do I increase the padding in `<tr>`? The headings have good padding but not the content rows. Are these easy to fix?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk You should be able apply a padding to the td's inside the tr.

Answer (score 1):

Add class "table" and tbody tab to your HTML. this will fix your issue.I made the changes in code below:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">

<table class="table">

    <thead>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Dates</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>With</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td ><a href="/events/winter/">Winter</a></td><td >27 February 2016 </td><td >10:00am - 4:00pm</td><td >Gordon Peterson&nbsp;</td><td class="elist-cost"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

example code here [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/EyJmoZ?editors=1000)